# Storage classes in Kotlin programming language

Tags: kotlin

I went through many sites, but, could not find the answer to this question.

In C, The storage classes are auto, extern, static, register etc. What are the storage classes in Kotlin Programming language?

Any link or tutorial would be appreciable. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html

Answer (score 2):

Since Kotlin runs on the JVM, my guess would be that most things valid for java would also apply to Kotlin.

check the comments and replies here: [related question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624462/where-does-class-object-reference-variable-get-stored-in-java-in-heap-or-stac)

roughly speaking: everything goes onto the heap, variables holding references to heap objects might be on the stack. And then, things like **register** are afaik not even possible in JVM languages (at least Java/Kotlin?). So the answer (assuming i got your question right) might be: Not available, not applicable, the JVM will take care of everything.