# When we create an object using new operator, does it use the actual .class file to create an object in java

Tags: java, class, classloader, new-operator

I am confused about a subject and can not find it on the web. 
As I understand it, when the program starts the class loader loads the `.class` files and store them in the memory as objects with the type `Class`.

My question is when we use:

```
Test test = new Test();
```

Is the new object created using `.class` file, or using the `Class` object already in the memory?

Comment: I think the unclear part is *As i understand when the program starts the class loader loads the .class files and store them in the memory as objects with the type Class.*

Comment: is that wrong? if so can you point me a direction where i can learn the execution cycle @YCF_L

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once a class is loaded into a JVM, the same class will not be loaded again for same class loader. New instance will be created from class object in memory (for same class loader).

Steps at high level (copied from https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-classloader/j-classloader.html)

1. Call findLoadedClass to see if already loaded the class.
2. If haven't loaded the class, get the bytes using findClass (overridden by class loader implementations).
3. If raw bytes found, call defineClass to turn them into a Class object. (example in AppClassLoader)
4. If the class resolved, call resolveClass to resolve the Class object.
5. If still don't have a class, throw a ClassNotFoundException.

   ```
   protected synchronized Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)
   throws ClassNotFoundException
   {
       // First, check if the class has already been loaded
     Class c = findLoadedClass(name);
        if (c == null) {
           try {
               if (parent != null) {
                 c = parent.loadClass(name, false);
                } else {
                   c = findBootstrapClass0(name);
               }
           } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
               // If still not found, then invoke findClass in order
              // to find the class.
                c = findClass(name);
            }
        }
       if (resolve) {
          resolveClass(c);
        }
       return c;
   }
   ```

Example all of following will print same hashCode and refers to same Test.class

```
    Test  test1 = new Test();
    Test test2 = new Test();
    System.out.println(test2.getClass().hashCode());
    System.out.println(test1.getClass().hashCode());
    System.out.println(Test.class.hashCode());
```

For more details
http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html?page=1

Comment: `If raw bytes found, call defineClass to turn them into a Class object.` So from this point on new instances will be created using that Class object ? And in my case i can access it using Test.class?

Comment: Yes, you can even create your custom class load inheriting from ClassLoader and try finding class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

Comment: For the second `new Test()` expression, the JVM will not even call `loadClass`, as identical symbolic references are resolved only once per class. This ensures that all references to `Test` within one class always resolve to the same class, even if you implemented a custom class loader overriding `loadClass` with a method doing weird things…

Answer (score 1):

A class (.class) gets loaded into the **method area**(1 Per JVM). This is also a logical part of the heap.

So in your case Test.class will be present in the method area when it is loaded thru main method or some other class as a dependency in the following structure :

**Method Area stores the following data per loaded class :**

1. run-time constant pool
2. field and method data
3. code for methods and constructors

When the `new Test()` is encountered, a new instance of the Test class will be created in the heap that represents an Object of type Test.

[image]

[Where does class, object, reference variable get stored in java. IN heap or stack? Where is heap or stack located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624462/where-does-class-object-reference-variable-get-stored-in-java-in-heap-or-stac)

The above post explains more clearly on the storage principle in JVM.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer.. Just to avoid confusion.. Does the method area holds the `class object (test.getClass())` or does it hold the `compiled .class` file which is Test.class file ?